# Logging sql error from inside shell script

Tags: linux, oracle, unix

i am trying to implement a error logging mechanism in shell script which will also give me errors inside a sql statement

I am planning to call my script from inside another script and redirecting the error to a logfile..
is there any better option   ? please help.

```
#!/bin/sh

./test.sh 2>&1 >> log_1.log
```

test.sh contains the follwing code

```
## testing error logging in sql

result=`sqlplus -s $username/$passwd@$db <<EOF
set serveroutout on
set pagesize 0
set heading off
set echo off
set feedback off
select first_name from employees;
exit;
EOF
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "Error exists"
else
echo "$result"
fi
```

--- Edited after testing the code given by Alex Pool

I did the changes but whenever I am getting an SQL error,log file is not getting generated instead the error is being shown at the command line..

Script name -test_error_log.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

output=`sqlplus -s -l hr/hr@xe << EOF
whenever sqlerror exit failure rollback
whenever oserror exit failure rollback
set serveroutput on
set heading off
set pagesize 0
set echo off

select **e.firs_name   --- wrong field name**
       ,d.department_name from 
employees e , departments d
where e.department_id=d.department_id ;

exit;
EOF`

echo $output
```

I am calling it from caller_shell.sh in the following way

script name : caller_shell.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

./test_error_log.sh 2>&1 log_file
```

When I execute ./caller_shell.sh from command line I am getting the error a
but not at the log_file but at the screen

```
ERROR at line 1: ORA-00904: "E"."FIRS_NAME": invalid identifier
```

Please let me know how to resolve this ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`whenever sqlerror`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve052.htm) to make SQL*Plus exit with an error code, which the shell script will see as the return code:

```
result=`sqlplus -l -s $username/$passwd@$db <<EOF
whenever sqlerror exit failure rollback
whenever oserror exit failure rollback
set serveroutput on
set pagesize 0
set heading off
set echo off
set feedback off
select first_name from employees;
exit 0;
EOF`
```

It will exit when the error is seen, and nothing after the point of failure will be attempted. Using `failure` makes it a generic failure code, but you can specify a particularly value if you prefer. But be aware of shell limits if you use your own value; in most shells anything above 255 will loop back round to zero, so it's not a good idea to try to exit with the SQL error code for example as you might get a real error that happens to end up as zero after it's been mod'ed. Using `rollback` means that if a failure occurs partway through a script it will roll back any (uncommitted) changes already made.

This will catch SQL errors and PL/SQL errors (unless those are caught by an exception handler and not re-raised), but won't catch SQL*Plus-specific errors - i.e. those starting `SP-`, such as from an invalid `set` command.

I've added a `-l` flag to the `sqlplus` command so it only tries to connect once, which is helpful for a non-interactive script - sometimes they can hang waiting for subsequent credentials, depending on the context and what else is in the script. I've also fixed the spelling of `serveroutput` and added a missing backtick...

Comment: Great explanation. +1 for `-l` option.

Comment: @Alex Thank you very much Sir .. Very Informative.
whenever sqlerror exit failure rollback

Comment: @Alex What does failure contains? sql err msg ? I dont have machine at this monent so cant really test it.

Comment: @AsfakulIslam - it's just a numeric value; with `failure` I think it's always 1. But you'll have the real error message in the output. E.g if you don't have an `emoloyees` table, you'll see the ORA-00942 in the SQL*Plus output, and `$?` will be 1 - so you'll generate your `"Error exists"` message too.

Comment: @AlexPoole Also if possible could you please let me know what does 
exec 2>&1 log_file.txt mean?

Comment: @AsfakulIslam - tacking new questions onto old ones (esp. answered ones) doesn't get you many views. `2>&1` means error output on the `stderr` stream is redirected to the standard output `stdout` stream. But you lost any redirection from that; what you have now does nothing with the output. As you originally had it, `2>&1 >> log_1.log` appended `stdout` to the file, so you saw nothing on screen. In your current execution, `2>&1 log_file`, the `log_file` part does nothing. [Read more](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).